# Asp.Net - Is there a way to set attribute to all controls of the application?

Tags: asp.net, button, double-click

I have a system and I had a problem today, when the user double-click on button control and the system process the operation twice.
I found a solution with this code on the button:

```
OnClientClick = "this.disabled = true; this.value = 'submiting ...';" UseSubmitBehavior = "false"
```

However, I have several pages in the system, with several buttons ... is there any way to set these attributes to all the buttons of the application?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a **clientSide approach** by using JQuery and **disabling all Submit controls** ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/njBjW/2/))

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(' :submit').click(function (event) {
        $(this).attr("disabled","true");
  });
});​
```

I am quite new to JQuery so if there are any better solutions or I am completly wrong, pls let me know!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but it seems that it is possible through skin file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom button. Here you have example how to create button that displays confirm window on client click. Almost what you wan't.

http://dhavalupadhyaya.wordpress.com/2008/07/20/creating-custom-controls-in-asp-net/

Than you would have to change all the asp:Buttons on every page to someTag:YourButton. Maybe simple Find/Replace. But I think there is possibility to configure in web.config so that ASP.NET uses someTag:YourButton everytime it sees asp:Button. But can't find now how to do it.